# c# jquery issues with limit characters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I've got a problem. I have a Gridview filled with a Datatable. When I display the result, I limit the number of characters (300) per rows. I put a button, when you click on it, it opens a pop-up and should display the whole result with no characters limitation. But the problem is that it doesn't display the whole result and I don't know how to do that, I tried to make an invisible datagridview to get its result but I think I'm doing it wrong 'cause it's like I didn't create it

Code html :

```
           <Columns>


               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aggregation">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Aggregation") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DerniereSolution">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("DerniereSolution") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DescriptionDemande">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("DescriptionDemande") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NomContact">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("NomContact") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Numero">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Numero") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SousRubrique">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("SousRubrique") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TitreDemande">
                   <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("TitreDemande") %></ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select">Select</a>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>

           </Columns>

       </asp:GridView>
```

Code Jquery :

```
jQuery.noConflict();



 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

       $(".select").click(function () {
           ClearBackgroundColourOfRows();
           var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
           $(tr).css('background-color', '#A1DCF2');

           <%  %>

           var children = $(tr).children();
           var agg = $(children[0]).html();
           var lastSol = $(children[1]).html();
           var descr = $(children[2]).html();
           var contact = $(children[3]).html();
           var num = $(children[4]).html();
           var rub = $(children[5]).html();
           var title = $(children[6]).html();

           var message = "<b>Titre Demande</b><br>" + title + "<br><br>" + "<b>Aggregation</b><br>" + agg + "<br><br>" + "<b>Dernière Solution</b><br>" + lastSol + "<br><br>" + "<b>Description Demande</b><br>" + descr + "<br><br>" + "<b>Nom Contact</b><br>" + contact + "<br><br>" + "<b>Numéro</b><br>" + num + "<br><br>" + "<b>Sous-Rubrique</b><br>" + rub;

           $(".modal-body").empty();
           $(".modal-body").html(message);
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
       });

       function ClearBackgroundColourOfRows() {
           $('#gvData tr').each(function () {
               $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
           });
       }

       $(".btn").click(function () {
           ClearBackgroundColourOfRows();
       });

   });
```

Code c# :

```
protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {



           if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {

               e.Row.Cells[2].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[2].ToString().Replace(tbSearch.Text, "<p>" + tbSearch.Text + "</p>");
               e.Row.Cells[6].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[6].ToString().Replace(tbSearch.Text, "<p>" + tbSearch.Text + "</p>");//highlight words

               e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[0].ToString().Substring(0, 300) + "...";//limit characters
               e.Row.Cells[1].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[1].ToString().Substring(0, 300) + "...";
               e.Row.Cells[2].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[2].ToString().Substring(0, 300) + "...";


       }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it possible to limit the string length in the .ASPX page instead of in the code-behind? This `<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("TitreDemande").ToString().Substring(0,300) %></ItemTemplate>` might yield different results. Might want to handle the strings that are less than 300 though as well... `<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("TitreDemande").ToString().Length > 300 ? Eval("TitreDemande").ToString().Substring(0,297) + "..." : Eval("TitreDemande").ToString() %></ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `gvData_RowDataBound` completely and use jQuery for limiting characters and displaying the full cell text in popup.Hope the example below helps you

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class CharacterLimitationExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        var d1 = new Data { Aggregation = "Row 1", DerniereSolution = "Row 1 really really long data", DescriptionDemande = "Row 1", NomContact = "Row 1", Numero = "Row 1", SousRubrique = "Row 1", TitreDemande = "Row 1" };
        var d2 = new Data { Aggregation = "Row 2", DerniereSolution = "Row 2 really really long data", DescriptionDemande = "Row 2", NomContact = "Row 2", Numero = "Row 2", SousRubrique = "Row 2", TitreDemande = "Row 2" };

        gvData.DataSource = new List<Data> { d1, d2 };
        gvData.DataBind();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public string Aggregation { get; set; }
    public string DerniereSolution { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionDemande { get; set; }
    public string NomContact { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string SousRubrique { get; set; }
    public string TitreDemande { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var count = 0;

            $('#gvData tr').each(function () {
                debugger;
                if (count != 0) {
                    var tr = $(this);

                    var children = $(tr).children();

                    var td1 = $(children)[0];
                    var span1 = $(td1).children()[0];
                    var data1 = $(span1).data('fulltext');
                    $(span1).text(data1.substring(0, 3) + "...");

                    var td2 = $(children)[1];
                    var span2 = $(td2).children()[0];
                    var data2 = $(span2).data('fulltext');
                    $(span2).text(data2.substring(0, 3) + "...");

                    var td3 = $(children)[2];
                    var span3 = $(td3).children()[0];
                    var data3 = $(span3).data('fulltext');
                    $(span3).text(data3.substring(0, 3) + "...");
                }
                count++;
            });

            $(".select").click(function () {
                ClearBackgroundColourOfRows();
                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                $(tr).css('background-color', '#A1DCF2');

                var children = $(tr).children();

                var agg = $(children[0]).find('span').data('fulltext');
                var lastSol = $(children[1]).find('span').data('fulltext')
                var descr = $(children[2]).find('span').data('fulltext')

                var contact = $(children[3]).html();
                var num = $(children[4]).html();
                var rub = $(children[5]).html();
                var title = $(children[6]).html();

                var message = "<b>Titre Demande</b><br>" + title + "<br><br>" + "<b>Aggregation</b><br>" + agg + "<br><br>" + "<b>Dernière Solution</b><br>" + lastSol + "<br><br>" + "<b>Description Demande</b><br>" + descr + "<br><br>" + "<b>Nom Contact</b><br>" + contact + "<br><br>" + "<b>Numéro</b><br>" + num + "<br><br>" + "<b>Sous-Rubrique</b><br>" + rub;

                $(".modal-body").empty();
                $(".modal-body").html(message);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });

            function ClearBackgroundColourOfRows() {
                $('#gvData tr').each(function () {
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
                });
            }

            $(".btn").click(function () {
                ClearBackgroundColourOfRows();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aggregation">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span data-fulltext='<%# Eval("Aggregation") %>'></span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DerniereSolution">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span data-fulltext='<%# Eval("DerniereSolution") %>'></span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DescriptionDemande">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span data-fulltext='<%# Eval("DescriptionDemande") %>'></span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NomContact">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("NomContact") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Numero">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Numero") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SousRubrique">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("SousRubrique") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TitreDemande">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("TitreDemande") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select">Select</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Limiting characters in ASP.NET GridView and displaying full text in modal popup]

Comment: Hi thank you for your help ! The function to limit characters works perfectly but when I click on the "select" nothing happens, and I get an error :  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined". I think it comes from the way I display my table, but I don't know how to do in another way to display all the rows with all the results

Comment: write debugger; after $(".select").click(function () { and step through your javascript.You shouldn't even be calling substring when you press select.Look carefully how I've done it in my example and try replicate on your side.As you can see my example works.If you copy and paste it in a brand new .aspx page you will see that it works

Comment: Yes I tried your exact code it works very well ! I'm gonna find the error, thank again !